# Float object is not iterable?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this code here and was wondering why it says that the float object is not iterable referring to line 8. Please help!

```
class bills:
    def __init__(self, type, amount, date):
        self.type = type
        self.amount = amount
        self.date = date
    
    def total(self):
        return sum(self.amount)

folder = []
folder.append(bills("Electric", 67.42, "04/10/20"))
folder.append(bills("Water", 22.09, "04/08/20"))
folder.append(bills("Mortgage", 625.00, "04/13/20"))
folder.append(bills("Disney+", 12.99, "04/05/20"))
folder.append(bills("Gym", 64.56, "04/01/20"))

for bills in folder:
    print(bills.type, bills.amount, bills.date)
for bills in folder:
    print(bills.total())
```

Comment: You are calling `sum` on a single float value... What exactly do you expect to happen? Please post the full error traceback

Comment: `sum(bill.amount for bill in folder)`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to calculate the total `amount` of all `bills` objects. But `total()` is an ***instance*** method and is not aware of the other objects... It should either be a regular function:

```py
def total(all_bills):
    return sum(bill.amount for bill in all_bills)

print(total(folder))
```

Or, you could implement the [`__add__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__add__) and [`__radd__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__radd__) methods to be able to call `sum` directly on a list of objects:

```py
class bills:
    [...]

    def __add__(self, other):
        try:
            return self.amount + other.amount
        except AttributeError:
            return self.amount + other

    def __radd__(self, other):
        return self.amount + other

[...]
print(sum(folder))
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to have total as a class method.  You can simply compute it by iterating through the bill objects in your folder, as follows:

```
class bills:
    def __init__(self, type, amount, date):
        self.type = type
        self.amount = amount
        self.date = date

folder = []
folder.append(bills("Electric", 67.42, "04/10/20"))
folder.append(bills("Water", 22.09, "04/08/20"))
folder.append(bills("Mortgage", 625.00, "04/13/20"))
folder.append(bills("Disney+", 12.99, "04/05/20"))
folder.append(bills("Gym", 64.56, "04/01/20"))

for bills in folder:
    print(bills.type, bills.amount, bills.date)

total = sum([bill.amount for bill in folder])
print(f'Total is: {total}')
```

Comment: Thank you. You all are amazing

Comment: @greglamm no problem. Make sure you upvote and accept the answer if it has helped you.